# jQuery ID matching

Tags: javascript, jquery

This Toggle on a mouseover event works fine:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".info").hide();
    jQuery(".trigger").mouseout(function(){
        jQuery(".info").slideUp(200);
    });
    jQuery(".trigger").mouseover(function(){
        jQuery(".info").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

but have too many objects so if i trigger some trigger, it shows me all areas with the info class. The easiest way would be adding an ID :

```
<div class="trigger" id="1">Details</div>
<div class=" info" id="1">
    <p> <b> Projektbeschreibung </b> </p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum one. </p>
</div>

<div class="trigger" id="2">Details</div>
<div class=" info" id="2">
    <p> <b> Projektbeschreibung </b> </p>
    <p> Lorem ipsum two. </p>
</div>
```

So the trigger is only triggering the info to witch its belongs.
I'm not very into jQuery, so my question is how do I get this id matching the js code?

Comment: **ID** should be unique. Its not a valid way to use same **ID** for more then one element.

Comment: It is **not remotely acceptable** to use the kind of language you used hidden in your HTML markup here on SO.

Comment: This is basically a "write this for me" request. Instead, read through the jQuery API, learn a bit about web programming, and try to figure out how to target a specific element.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the callbacks, refer to the object called with `this`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".info").hide();
    jQuery(".trigger").mouseout(function(){
         jQuery(this).slideUp(200);
    });
    jQuery(".trigger").mouseover(function(){
         jQuery(this).slideToggle();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use `this` in handler function which refers to `Element` over which event is invoked!

[**`jQueryObject.next([SELECTOR])`**](https://api.jquery.com/next/) will select immediate sibling element of the `current` element.

**Note:** Remove Duplicate IDs from document as, [***There must not be multiple `elements` in a `document` that have the same `id` value.***](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery(".info").hide();
  jQuery(".trigger").mouseout(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".info").slideUp(200);
  });
  jQuery(".trigger").mouseover(function() {
    jQuery(this).next(".info").slideDown(200);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger">Details</div>
<div class=" info">
  <p> <b> Projektbeschreibung </b> 
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum one.</p>
</div>

<div class="trigger">Details</div>
<div class=" info">
  <p> <b> Projektbeschreibung </b> 
  </p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum two.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(".trigger").hover(function() {
    $('#' + $(this).attr('data-target')).stop(true).slideToggle();
  });
});
```

```css
.info {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="trigger" data-target="item-1">Details</div>
<div class=" info" id="item-1"><p> <b> Projektbeschreibung </b> </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum one. </p>
</div>

<div class="trigger" data-target="item-2">Details</div>
<div class=" info" id="item-2"><p> <b> Projektbeschreibung </b> </p>
<p> Lorem ipsum two. </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

@Jonathan it's easy to do with JQuery.

in your JQuery function you just need make some tweaks to get the ID and perform the function as expected.

`jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(".info").hide();
    jQuery(".trigger").mouseout(function(){
      var elem_id = $(this).attr('id');
      jQuery(".info#"+elem_id).slideUp(200);
    });
    jQuery(".trigger").mouseover(function(){
      var elem_id = $(this).attr('id');
      jQuery(".info#"+elem_id").slideToggle();
    });
    });`

Try above code.